# subquery in SqlDataSource causes error (asp.net )

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, subquery

Error:  (Microsoft Visual Studio using ASP.NET/C#):

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery  follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

More details:  The previous error is caused by the following code.  It is a GridView and the associated SQLDataSource.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="sqlAll" AllowPaging="True" 
    onpageindexchanging="grdGrid_PageIndexChanging">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="A" HeaderText="A" 
            SortExpression="A" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="G" HeaderText="G" 
            SortExpression="PeriodCode" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" HeaderText="Value" SortExpression="Value" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlAll" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionDB01 %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [A], [G], [H] FROM [Table1] 
    WHERE [B] = 
        (SELECT [B] 
          FROM [Table2] 
            WHERE [C] = @C) 
    AND ([D] = 
        (SELECT [D] 
            FROM [Table3] 
              WHERE [E] = @E))
    AND ([A] < @A) AND ([A] > @A2)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlBlah2" Name="AreaName" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlBlah" Name="B" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtEndA" Name="A" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtStartA" Name="A2" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="Decimal" />
         </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
```

(The @Letter mean they're from a dropdownlist reference.)

Comments:  Obviously, there are subqueries in the code.  However, how do I work around the non-subquery limitation?  :(  How are these things typically handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 (SELECT [B] 
      FROM [Table2] 
        WHERE [C] = @C) 
 change this query to like this
     (SELECT TOP 1[B] 
       FROM [Table2] 
        WHERE [C] = @C) 


 or use IN instead of =

     WHERE [B] IN 
      (SELECT [B] 
      FROM [Table2] 
        WHERE [C] = @C)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your sub-query is, when you try to do some operation like =, <, <=, >, >=, it can only compare one value to another, not one value to a set of value. Assume like this, your sub query **SELECT [B] FROM [Table2] WHERE [C] = @C** returns more than one value, it will throw this error.

You can use this sub-query, if you are sure that the sub-query will only return one value (maybe because [C] is the primary key), otherwise you can use @Devesh answer.